# Phantom table entries

Tags: lua

There seem to be two approaches to dynamically adding elements to tables

```
table.insert(t, index, value) -- optional index
```

and

```
t[#t+1] = value
```

according to the docs if the index is left off, `table.insert(t, value)` should behave exactly like `t[#t+1] = value`.

For some reason even though I only store two values in my table, I see four entries when I iterate through with `ipairs`:

```
words = {}
for i = 0, 1 do  
   local word = io.read()   -- word is familiarize
   table.insert(words , word)
   -- american to english spelling
   word = word:gsub("ze","se") 
   table.insert(words , word)
end

for i,v in ipairs(words) do
    print(i,v)
end

-- prints
-- 1    
-- 2    
-- 3    familiarize
-- 4    familiarise
```

Any idea where these extra two entries come from?

Comment: Did you meant to `insert` into the table `words` and not the table `t`?

Comment: You call `.insert` twice, in a loop that runs twice. So naturally you will have four elements...

Comment: @Anko Yes that was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm assuming you meant to `insert` into `words`, not `t`.)

You're still going twice around that loop; once for `i == 0` and once for `i == 1`. We can add some prints to demonstrate:

```
words = {}
for i = 0, 1 do
    print "inserting two..."
    local word = "familiarize"
    table.insert(words, word)
    -- american to english spelling
    word = word:gsub("ze","se")
    table.insert(words, word)
end

for i,v in ipairs(words) do
    print(i,v)
end
```

This gives the following output:

```
inserting two...
inserting two...
1   familiarize
2   familiarise
3   familiarize
4   familiarise
```

That should make things clearer.

Comment: interesting, I was not seeing that result. I also was under the impression  that `for i = 0, 1` executed once. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. In Lua, the `for _ = a,b` construct includes both end values. This is unlike most C-ish languages, where you might do `for (i=0;i<1;i++)` and expect the loop to run just for `i == 0`. This is because including both ends works better with Lua's 1-based array indices (C's are 0-based).